# Is there an api or method that I can overlay square grids on google map?

Tags: dictionary, gis

Is there an api or method that I can overlay square grids on google map like the below image?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COGem.jpg)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_U3QC18xogc

I am trying to find a method to build a service where people can post based on the grid squares.

I have looked into google map APIs but it seems it does not provide anything like that.